# How to trace error message in libav

Tags: libavcodec, libav

I'm writing a simple program to decode any input audio file into pcm16/mono/wav file, using libav. Or, I supposed it was simple.

After struggling a lot, reading lots of sample code (like avconv/avplay), I've managed to code something that should work.

However, it's not working. The demuxing/decoding parts seems to work fine, but the encoding part failed with the following message:

```
mathematics.c:61: av_rescale_rnd: Assertion `c > 0' failed.
```

Here is the code extract:

```
printf("Fill Frame\n");
avcodec_fill_audio_frame(oframe, _oCodecCtx->channels, _oCodecCtx->sample_fmt, frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0], 0);
printf("Frame filled\n");
ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(_oCodecCtx, &opkt, oframe, &got_packet);
if (ret < 0) {
   printf("Error encoding audio frame\n");
   return 1;
}
```

"Fill Frame" And "Frame filled" are displayed before the error appears. So, I think its thrown by `avcodec_encode_audio2`. However, this function doesn't call `av_rescale_rnd` in its source code.

So here is the question: is there a way to know who called this function, without modifying/recompiling libav source code?

Comment: you can use gdb to and put breakpoint at the funtion av_rescale_rnd.once you reach the brekpoint just check the stacktrace and it will tell you from which function is this funtion called.